# Does $X\times Y$ have countable chain condition?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ have countable chain condition. Does $X\times Y$ have countable chain condition?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consistently not necessarily.  A consistent counterexample, under, for example, the assumption $\mathbf{V} = \mathbf{L}$ or just [$\diamondsuit$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle), would be a [Souslin line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin%27s_problem), which has the ccc, but whose square does not.

However, also consistently yes.  In particular, [Martin's Axiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin%27s_axiom), $\sf{MA}$ (or even the fragment $\sf{MA} (\aleph_1)$), implies that any product of ccc spaces is ccc.

Comment: Also just adding one Cohen real adds a Suslin tree.